# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest:

Tags: php, laravel, vite, laravel-9, assetbundle

i'm using Asset Bundling (Vite) to show my css and js files, but i'm getting this error

```
Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/demo/demo.css.
```

there is a dot at the end of the address.

this is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/demo/demo.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

And I use this code in blade:

```
@vite(['resources/demo/demo.css'])
```

"laravel":v9.30.1

PHP v8.1.6

"vite": "^3.0.0"

Comment: @vite('resources/css/app.css') try this

Comment: @UmerFayyaz only this css file works and other files gives error

Answer (score 0):

in ur vite config file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/css/material-dashboard.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/demo/demo.css'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

run this command : `npm run build`

then congratulations !

Comment: thanks 
i add this to my codes but still gives me error

Comment: unfortunately the command doesn't work

Comment: I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

Check your package.json. Verify the script for build is written.

```
  "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch"
    },
```

Now run this command : `npm run build`